# Indications for surgery for Haglund's heel?

Tags: surgery, orthopedics, bursitis, heel

[Haglund's heel](http://www.healthline.com/health/haglund-deformity) is a well known condition. When, and why can surgery be recommended? Is there any literature or studies on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Haglund's syndrome** is defined as soft tissue and bony abnormalities in the retrocalcaneal region such as retrocalcaneal bursitis, superficial tendo Achilles bursitis, and thickening and/or inflammation of the Achilles tendon. Patients with Haglund's syndrome show a prominent bony contour of the posterior calcaneus.

Below an MRI showing typical Haglund's syndrome abnormalities (the white part just under the Achilis tendon and the bony projection of the calcaneus):

[image]

Several studies have investigated the best management option for patients with Haglund's syndrome. The open access review by Sofka et al provides a good overview:

Here some facts regarding **conservative treatment**:

> **Conservative treatment options include reassessment of the footwear
>   the patient is currently wearing, the use of heel inserts, and oral
>   anti-inflammatory medication.** The effects of heel elevation on the
>   relationship between the calcaneal bursal projection and the Achilles
>   tendon and retrocalcaenal bursa have been described. Although the
>   size of the calcaneal bursal projection remains the same when the heel
>   is elevated, the plantar calcaneal pitch angle decreases and shifts
>   the osseous calcaneal bursal projection away from the retrocalcaneal
>   soft tissues, decreasing friction and irritation

Here some facts regarding **surgical treatment**:

> **Surgical treatment options, including retrocalcaneal decompression and
>   calcaneal ostectomy or osteotomy, have varying results.**
>   Inadequate bone resection can lead to recurrence of symptoms, with
>   other postsurgical complications potentially including scar formation
>   with nerve entrapment, weakening or rupture of the Achilles tendon,
>   and nonunion of the calcaneal osteotomy.

Sources:

Sofka CM, Adler RS, Positano R, Pavlov H, Luchs JS. Haglund’s Syndrome: Diagnosis and Treatment Using Sonography. HSS Journal. 2006;2(1):27-29. doi:10.1007/s11420-005-0129-8.

http://radiopaedia.org/cases/haglund-syndrome-5 for the MRI image